# Break between two forms when printing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to page break like this between two forms:

```js
document.getElementById("btnPrint1").onclick = function () {
    printElement(document.getElementById("printThis1")); 
}
function printElement(elem) {
    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);    
    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");    
    if (!$printSection) {
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }
    console.log($printSection);
    $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
    window.print();
}

var linha = ``;

linha = `
<table class="report-container">
  <thead class="report-header">
    <tr>
      <th class="report-header-cell">
        <div class="header-info">
          <div class="article">
          teste, teste,teste
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody header-info>
    <tr>
      <td class="report-content-cell">                   
        <div class="main">
        teste1, teste1,teste1
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody> 
</table>`;
           
$("#retorc6").html(linha);

linha1 = `
<table class="report-container">
  <thead class="report-header">
    <tr>
      <th class="report-header-cell">
        <div class="header-info">
           teste2, teste2,teste2
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody header-info>
    <tr>
      <td class="report-content-cell">                   
        <div class="main">
        teste3, teste3,teste3
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody> 
</table>`;
           
$("#reto6").html(linha1);
```

```css
@media screen {
  #printSection {
      display: none;
  }
}

@media print {
  body * {
    visibility:hidden;
    
  }

  #printSection, #printSection * {
    visibility:visible;
  }
  #printSection {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
      margin: 2mm;
  }
  table.report-container {
    page-break-after:always;
  }
  thead.report-header {
    display:table-header-group;
  }
  tfoot.report-footer {
    display:table-footer-group;
  } 
  table.report-container div.article {
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
  }
  .pagebreak { page-break-before: always; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info show-side-btn" id="btnPrint1" data-show="show-side-navigation1" style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
               
<div id="printThis1" class="printThis1">
  <form role="form" action="#!" id="retorc6">
  </form>
  <div class="pagebreak"> </div>
  <form role="form" action="#!" id="reto6">
    </form>
</div>
```

I verify that you create both pages, but you are not putting the first form on the first page and the second form on the second page.

The objective was to put the forms separated by page.

I've already researched and verified in the examples I found that it works, but with me it's not working. Can you help?

Comment: It’s due to the fact that you positioned `#printSection` absolute.

Comment: @CBroe But if you remove the `#printSection absolute`, when printing, the first two pages are empty and the form only appears on the third page

Comment: That’s probably because of all the stuff you hid using `visibility:hidden` - which only hides the elements, but keeps their original space reserved.

Comment: Yes, to hide an element without occupying any space, use `display:none`.

Comment: @NcXNaV If you use display:none it hides everything and doesn't show anything later when printing

Comment: Did you try to use `display:block` for print section?

Comment: @NcXNaV I tried it now, but unformats the print